# ASIHTTPRequest: prioritizing requests

Tags: ios, queue, asihttprequest

Using `ASIHTTPRequest`, can i prioritize the requests or specify their order?

I'm using `ASIHTTPRequest` along with `ASINetworkQueue`. For example, i send Request 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .... By default `ASIHTTPRequest` support 4 concurrent connections, so as a result Request 5 starts when any one of the previous requests are completed. Now, in my case, i may need to post a Request (say A) before Request 5. Request A maybe triggered as a result of Request 1 (*success*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequests are a subclass `NSOperation` and are run inside an `NSOperationQueue`, so you can set the priority like so:

```
request.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityHigh;
```

Comment: This is not the answer i was looking for, but marking as the answer anyways.